# Setting up PWA break php authentification/redirect

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I added PWA into my site using that tutorial:

https://github.com/yarekc/pwa

The goal of the PWA is simply to add home page start icon.

After adding that script to my index.php, people could not enter my website anymore: the authentification session/redirection page was leading to index.php 
This was happening in chrome users.
I had to remove the registerSW.js page so people could enter again.

Any idea of what could cause that bug ?

Regards

Comment: You don't need a service worker to get a homepage start icon.

Comment: I think I need it indeed in latest chrome. Do you have a working sample somewhere ?